# Can awk treat values in records differently based on the first value?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, awk

I'm relatively new to awk. I'm creating a awk script that will read a file that has the general format:

```bash
NAME firstName lastName
PAY cost numberOfPayments
END
```

My file will look something like this:

```bash
NAME Jane Doe
PAY 5.00 2
PAY 2.00 10
END
NAME John Doe
PAY 10.00 5
PAY 4.00 3
PAY 1.00 20
END
```

And the amount of payments between `NAME` to `END` can vary, and there can be multiple names (this is just a sample).

This is my awk script:

```c
# !/bin/awk

BEGIN { total=0; RS = "END"; }
{
    if (match($1, "NAME")) {
        print $2;
    }
    if (match($1, "SAVE")) {
        total = total + ($2 * $3);
        print total;
    }
}
```

The first value should recognize what action we are preforming (`PAY` vs. `NAME`). Based on that, I should either print `NAME` or find the total amount which is found by multiplying the cost by the number of payments. `END` is what I'm using to signify that's the end of the record for that specific customer.

The output of this particular file should be:

```bash
Jane 30
John 82
```

I've tried several ways but I cannot seem to get the desired output. Any help to get this working would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First, the code:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

$1 == "NAME" { printf "%s ", $2 }
$1 == "PAY" { total += $2 * $3 }
$1 == "END" { print total; total = 0 }
```

If you call the script `tally`, mark it executable with `chmod +x tally`, and you are in the directory that contains it, you can run it on the input file *`file`* with:

```bash
./tally file
```

On the input text you showed, it gives the output you wanted:

```bash
Jane 30
John 82
```

You have not stated what you want the output to look like when there are multiple names with no `END` in between, but I assume you want to output the first name for each. Consider this input file:

```bash
NAME Jane Doe
NAME Clark Kent
PAY 5.77 9
END
NAME John Doe
PAY 14.22 6
NAME Linda Lee Danvers
PAY .25 4
END
```

That produces this output:

```bash
Jane Clark 51.93
John Linda 86.32
```

### What it does, and why:

In the problem you are trying to solve, each of what should conceptually be thought of as a record is a "stanza" of multiple lines, where a line may consist of multiple fields. Each datum therefore has three "coordinates": **⟨stanza, line, field⟩**

But AWK's fundamental abstraction is instead **⟨record, field⟩**. AWK is still a good choice for this problem, but you will have to decide how you want to map the natural abstraction of the problem to the abstraction your tool supports directly. In your code, it looks like you may be trying to treat each stanza as a single record, since you've made `END` the input record separator (`RS = "END"`). That can be made to work, and I hope other answers are posted that show how. **But I suggest having `awk` treat each line as a record instead.**

The reason is that there is already another way to think about your input data: as a list of *commands*, one per line, where:

1. Your `NAME` command outputs the word that follows it. Conceptually this is a first name.
2. Your `PAY` command accumulates products into a variable `total`. Specifically, it multiplies the two values that follow it and increases `total` by that amount.
3. Your `END` command prints `total`, ends the line, and resets `total` back to zero.

### How it works, line by line:

**`#!/usr/bin/awk -f`**

In Ubuntu, `awk` is located in `/usr/bin` and not `/bin`. The `-f` flag is required (on any OS) to tell AWK that the next argument, [which is the filename of the script itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), is to be interpreted as a script rather than as the name of an input file to process.

**No `BEGIN` rule**

You could make one and set `tally = 0` in it, but you don't need to because AWK allows arithmetic on uninitialized variables and treats them as zero. (If you were running `gawk --lint -f tally file` then you might want to include the assignment explicitly to avoid a "reference to uninitialized variable" warning.) I put a blank line here, but you don't have to.

**`$1 == "NAME" { printf "%s ", $2 }`**

When the first field is `NAME`, print the second field `$2` as a string (`%s`) followed by a space.

**`$1 == "PAY" { total += $2 * $3 }`**

When the first field is `PAY`, increase the value of `total` by the product of the second and third fields.

**`$1 == "END" { print total; total = 0 }`**

When the first field is `END`, print the value of `total`. The `print` statement automatically appends the output record separator, which is a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) since you haven't set `ORS` otherwise. Then set `total` back to zero to prepare for the next stanza (if any).

Comment: Thank you so much! This went above and beyond any answer I was expecting on here. Also thank you for assisting in editing my question, I apologize if it caused any confusion (but I can tell by your response it didn't hurt too much). Again, thank you very much. I think I have become a lot more familiar with awk!